# Mitzvah of eating sheep for Parshat Yitro

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Many communities have a custom to consume sheep for the Shabbat of Parshat Yitro. Why is this done?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Downvoter: This question is Purim Torah and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the Purim Torah policy. Unless you didn't like the joke. In which case, I hear you.

Comment: @SethJ http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20144103#20144103

Answer (score 6):

This is related etymologically by R' Hirsch: The giving of the Torah is referred to as מטן תורה, mutton torah. As such, it is proper to consume mutton on the Shabbat of Parshat Yitro. It is also permitted to do so on Shavuot, however it is customary instead to eat sheep's cheese, [as we do not eat meat then](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7875/4504). Bedieved, when no mutton is available, one may consume lamb, as it would be mutton the next year.

Comment: groan worthy. +1

Answer (score 4):

When the Jews left Egypt, a land where [sheep were worshiped as deities](/q/12741), they needed seven weeks to leave behind the vestiges of sheep-worhip and prepare themselves to receive the Torah and become God's nation as described in *parashas Yisro*. Therefore, when God appeared to them and presented them with the Decalogue, He included a reference to how far they had come, how much they had grown. He said ([20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm):2–5,in loose translation):

> אָנֹכִי ה׳ אֱלֹקֶיךָ אֲשֶׁר הוֹצֵאתִיךָ מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם מִבֵּית עֲבָדִים. לֹא יִהְיֶה לְךָ אֱלֹהִים אֲחֵרִים עַל פָּנָי. לֹא תַעֲשֶׂה לְךָ פֶסֶל וְכָל תְּמוּנָה אֲשֶׁר **בַּ**שָּׁמַיִם מִמַּעַל וַאֲשֶׁר **בָּ**אָרֶץ מִתָּחַת וַאֲשֶׁר **בַּ**מַּיִם מִתַּחַת לָאָרֶץ. לֹא תִשְׁתַּחֲוֶה לָהֶם וְלֹא תָעָבְדֵם
>
> I am God, your god, who has taken you out of Egypt, the place of worshipers. You're not going to have any other gods along with me. You're not going to make a graven image of — *baa* — heavens or of — *baa* — earth or of — *baa* — water. You won't bow to them or worship them.

To commemorate this event, we have a custom to eat sheep the week of *parashas Yisro*.

Comment: "[T]he place of worshipers?"

Comment: @SethJ "_bes avadim_". As in _oved avoda zara_

Comment: Is that part of the joke?

Comment: @SethJ, well, what relevance would "place of slaves" be? Surely God wouldn't include that in there while He's talking about sheep-worship. He must've meant "place of worshipers".

Answer (score 2):

This is because Yisro sheepishly admitted that the Jewish religion is the truth. As a Zecher to that we eat sheep.

Comment: He did so _sheepishly_? I don't get that sense from the pesukim.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I do not recall such a Mitzva either.

Comment: Downvoter: This question is Purim Torah and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the Purim Torah policy. Unless you didn't like the joke. In which case, I hear you.