# Trying to understand "Dairy on Shavuos based on the Mishna Berura"

Tags: dairy, mishnah-berurah

In [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7875/why-do-we-eat-milchigs-dairy-on-shavuos) to Why do we eat dairy on Shavuos "Monica Cellio" mentions "They just got the laws of kosher slaughter and weren't yet prepared". This is based on the [Mishna Berura 494:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=203). My question on this reason is The Mon started falling on the 16th of Iyar, the year the Jews left Egypt, [Rashi Kidushin 38a - 5 lines from the top](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14313&st=&pgnum=76&hilite=) thus when they came back from receiving the Torah they ate Mon. Then what difference does it make that they were unable to slaughter, they ate Mon?

Comment: No source is provided, but the halacha yomit email I received seems to say that they specifically ate milchigs on that day "The Mishna Berurah provides another reason for the milchigs. Included in the Aseres Hadibros that Klal Yisrael heard on Shavuos morning, were components of the complete Torah. When the Yidden returned home after Matan Torah, there was not enough time for them to kasher meat in accordance with the many halachos that they had just learned. Therefore, they opted to eat milchigs. Today, we eat milchigs as a reminder of the meal Bnei Yisroel ate that day."

Comment: It's a popular reason due to its "lomdishe" aspect, but I suspect the Mishna Brura brings that reason so people make a lot of pilpul on Shavuos rather than for its plausibility. See [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/he-il/kitveyet/bisde_hemed/farkas-minhag.htm) about R. Yakovson's view of that reason.

Comment: They also had Slav and other animals with them (what did they use for Korbanot?).